# App on Facebook running over http

Tags: php, facebook

Facebook announced that all the app that run on facebook should use HTTPS.

I wounder how these apps are running over HTTP.Is there any way to force facebook to use HTTP ?

https://www.facebook.com/philipshomelivingindia/app_208195102528120

Right and give view frame source,you'ii get the below link,

http://www.social-digitalpromotion.com/Philips/Middle-EastAndItalian-recipe-contest/index.html

https://www.facebook.com/VisitKerala/app_208195102528120

http://dunamisworld.com/keralaholidays/index.php

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps need to support HTTP and HTTPS or they won't be accessible to users using whichever HTTP(S) setting the app doesn't support - if you're seeing apps via HTTP instead of HTTPS, you're almost certainly using Facebook without HTTPS enabled on the account - HTTPS-enabled accounts can only see HTTPS compatible apps and vice-versa

Comment: look at the first example you gave and inspect the DOM tree - Facebook is loaded in HTTPS, Facebook loads the app iframe in HTTPS, and then the iframe loads another iframe via HTTP, throwing a mixed content warning for me - the developer of that app is 'doing it wrong'